# How to check value of td element inside parent tr element from another child td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

I´m using the DataTables table plug-in for jQuery. I have 4 columns, one of them contains buttons (Edit&Delete). I need to check the value of another column (in the same parent tr element) upon clicking one of the buttons using JavaScript/jQuery.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1">0 <!-- I need this number --> </td>
  <td>Exercise 1</td>
  <td>nl</td>
  <td class=" dt-center"> <!-- this element conatains the buttons --> </td>
</tr>
```

Could someone helpt me out? Thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the button, then you can ask for the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `tr` and then [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the specific `td` and ask for the `text` inside it.

`$(this).closest("tr").find(".sorting_1").text()`

```js
$('.getvalue').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest("tr").find(".sorting_1").text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">0 </td>
    <td>Exercise 1</td>
    <td>nl</td>
    <td class=" dt-center"> <button class="getvalue">get value</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">2</td>
    <td>Exercise 2</td>
    <td>n2</td>
    <td class=" dt-center"> <button class="getvalue">get value</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```